# Почему не показывается json файл по указанному роуту?

Tags: golang, create-react-app, golang-gin

Написал такой код

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/static"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./client/build", true)))
    router.Use(static.Serve("/export", static.LocalFile("./server/db.json", true)))
    
    api := router.Group("/api")
    {
        api.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "pong api/"})
        })

        api.GET("/export", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "pong api/export"})
        })
    }

    router.Run(":5000")
}
```

В папке *server* лежит тестовый файл *db.json*

```
{
    "items": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Яблоки",  "price": "$2" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Персики", "price": "$5" }
    ] 
}
```

Этот JSON-объект взял отсюда https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html и принимаю как в статье и написано

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./api")
    .then(response => {
      console.log("router: /api");
      console.log("response: ", response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => console.log("json: ", json));

    fetch("./api/export")
    .then(response => {
      console.log("router: /api/export");
      console.log("response: ", response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => console.log("json: ", json))
  }
```

Но по адресу *localhost:5000/api/export* показывает такой *json*
`{"message": "pong api/export"}`

Почему так происходит?
Думал, что строка

```
router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./client/build", true)))
```

развернет приложение на `localhost:5000/`,
а строка

```
router.Use(static.Serve("/export", static.LocalFile("./server/db.json", true)))
```

развернет файл *db.json* по адресу `localhost:5000/export`.
Ну и группировка обоих роутов в корень `/api`

```
router.Group("/api")
```

Тогда же приложение должно быть на адресе `localhost:5000/api/`,
а *db.json* — на адресе `localhost:5000/api/export` ?

P.S. добавляю изменение, неправильно понял группировку роутов, тем не менее проблема не решена, файл JSON не отображается по роуту.

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./client/build", true)))
    router.GET("/export", static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./server/db.json", true)))
    router.GET("/root", handleDataPerJson)
    router.Run(":5000")
}

func handleDataPerJson(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Carabas-Barabas connected!"})
}
```

На роуте *localhost:5000/export* файла *db.json* нет.

Answer (score 1):

группировка работает не так, как вы ожидаете. Группировка как раз нужна для того, чтобы объединять несколько эндпоинтов в одну. вместо того, чтобы писать

```
api.GET("/api/", ....
api.GET("api/export",
```

вы завернули в группу и опустили префикс api. Также группировка помогает управлять валидацей, верификацией и т.п. конкретно нужных эндпоинтов.

в вашем случае роуты будут такие

```
GET /             "client/build"
GET /export       "server/db.json" 
GET /api          "message": "pong api/"
GET /api/export   "message": "pong api/export"
```

Примечание: не получится по одному роуту указывать 2 разных хэндлера. поэтому, все 4 роута должны быть разные

Comment: Спасибо, но если закомментить строку с /export и вставить обработчик router.GET("/export", static.Serve("/export", static.LocalFile("./server/db.json", true))), то при переходе на localhost:5000/api/export  нет никакого db.json, вроде бы переброс на localhost:5000// был

Comment: @Tim Вам уже написал автор выше - ваш путь до JSON файла - это http://server/export, а не http://server/api/export.

Comment: @DanielProptopov, добавил дополнение в конец вопроса, чтобы понятно было.

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в функции

```
static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./client/build", true))
```

Первый её аргумент совсем не должен повторять имя папки/файла из структуры проекта, а второй аргумент должен указывать на папку с файлами (либо файл) внутри проекта. В данном случае папка ***./client/build*** будет располагаться по роуту *http://localhost:5000/*, где последний слеш ***/*** и является первым аргументом рассматриваемой функции.
В моём случае файл внутри проекта расположен по пути ***./server/db.json***. Если написать функцию так

```
static.Serve("/database", static.LocalFile("./server", true))
```

то по роуту *http://localhost:5000/database* будет имя файла ***db.json***, при клике на который произойдёт проваливание на роут *http://localhost:5000/db.json*, т.о. произошел выход из ***database***, а значит и из папки ***./server***, но вне её файла ***db.json*** нет, следовательно, *404 not found*.
Поэтому правильно будет так

```
static.Serve("/database/", static.LocalFile("./server", true))
```